# printing a series of characters

Tags: shell, scripting, printf, ascii, seq

My ultimate goal here is to generate a block of text that can be used to test out various fonts at a terminal.  I want to generate the file as basically an ascii chart.  A series of characters from 1 to 255 will do, I'm not worried about bells, or white space or anything, very simple.

I know if I wanted to type out all the numbers, I could do something like this:

```
printf '\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

But I don't want to have to type them all out.  I know I can use `printf` and `seq` with a sub-shell to generate some hex

```
printf %x' ' `seq 65 90`
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a
```

Can somebody help me connect the dots here?

I don't need a formal ascii table, but I would like pretty much all the visible characters so I can better test the various fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
perl -e 'for(65..90) { printf "%c", $_ }'
```

Or, if you insist to do it with `printf(1)` on Linux:

```
printf $( printf '\\x%02x' $( seq 65 90 ) )
```

Or, with `printf(1)` on *BSD:

```
printf $( printf '\\x%02x' $( jot - 65 90 1 ) )
```

Comment: thanks, I feel like I always forget about perl, I went with this: `perl -e 'for(33..79) { printf "%d\t%c\t\t%d\t%c\n", $_, $_, $_+47, $_+47 }'`

Answer (score 3):

POSIX one:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(n=33;n<=90;n++)printf "%c",n}'                              
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Perl one:

```
$ perl -e 'print chr for 33..90'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash >= 3.0`, `ksh93r` and above, `zsh`:

```
printf $( printf '\\x%02x' {65..90})
```